# Use View Binding in only some of activities or fragments instead of whole App

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

i just read an article about view binding in Android and I was thinking to use it in my App as it has many benefits over conventional "findViewById" method. I tried to search a way that if I can use it only in some of the activities(as I have so many activities and fragments that I cant simply write ignore this for view binding).I was thinking to make changes gradually so I need to know the best way from the experienced persons who also switched to this in a big project. Thank you

Comment: You can use it in "just a few places" if you **didn't** create something terrible like `BaseActivity<T: ViewDataBinding>`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce the document says "Once view binding is enabled in a module, it generates a binding class for each XML layout file present in that module." so it will generate autometically for each file rather than if i just want it to create only for 2 activities i nstead of 100.Is there a way that it generate binding classes only for those 2 activities?

Comment: Why does it matter? If you are not using them and you use Proguard, they will be pruned from the project in release mode anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling ViewBinding in your Gradle file will not break your existing code. If you want to incorporate ViewBinding with a specific activity or fragment, you will just have to implement it properly within that activity/fragment.

Comment: can you let me know how? my only concern is that if I want to add view binding in 2 classes out of 100 the rest 98 activities don't create binding classes automatically.

Comment: Like the others have said, Proguard will take care of any unused classes for this case so that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you worry about creating many new classes, the best way is to enable R8 shrinking in release builds. This way all unused view binding classes will be removed from release builds, so they won't impact the size of your app.